# Star WebPRNT JS SDK defining model and port name

Tags: javascript, ios, thermal-printer

I will try and contact Star directly but just in case I get an answer quicker from SO crowd.

Their SDK [here](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/en/_sampleProgram.htm) and their app [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/star-webprnt-browser-free/id911301767?mt=8) works fine with my SM-L200 printer using Star WebPRNT JS SDK.

However, trying to do the same using the SDK is not so straightforward. The app uses the HTML/JS code found [here](http://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/sdk_webprnt/sample/A001.html). But using the same thing from a Safari browser page (for example) does not work.

One must define the model and port name, from the [instructions](http://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/sdk_webprnt/sample/howto_en.html), but from the two JS functions defined in StarWebPrintTrader and StarWebPrintBuilder I cannot see where I could define the model and port name.

I would assume, the iOS app, gets the model and port name from the settings and passes it into the SDK.

How do I correctly send a print job to my SM-L200 using `StarWebPrintTrader.prototype.sendMessage()`?

Thanks

Edit: I contacted Star and I was told (non)mobile browsers at this moment are not able to communicate with Bluetooth devices. So unless native SDK code is used or JS WebPRNT run within Star WebPRNT browser, it is not possible to print to any Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Need more points to create better tags.

Comment: I have asked for Star support too
http://dev.starmicronics.com/supports/technicalsupport.aspx

Comment: any help on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390374/how-to-connect-to-a-sk1-sanei-thermal-printer-using-star-webprnt-js-sdk-connecte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this ..

var trader = new StarWebPrintTrader({url: '//localhost:8001/StarWebPrnt/SendMessage'});
var builder = new StarWebPrintBuilder();

And then do all the things you need.

Note that the Star WebPRNT browser doesn't (or at least didn't) support https, so you may have issues if your host app requires https.

The browser provides the bridge between the web application and the iOS's support for Bluetooth. The browser itself isn't aware of the printer directly as it has no Bluetooth support. The Star WebPRNT browser is Safari+Bluetooth support+localhost:8001.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, I think that is still missing both printer model and "port name" which is set from the Star WebPRNT Browser app from the settings. The SDK StarWebPrintTrader constructor does not take anything more than 

this.blackmark_sensor, this.papertype, this.checkedblock, this.url;

Comment: The JS based SDK doesn't have any need to know about the printer or its capabilities. That's up to the developer to implement if needed.

Comment: Ah. Are you trying to use the JS based SDK in an app that is not running in the Star WebPRNT Browser? If so, it's not going to happen. The browser opens up a channel to the printer via http://localhost:8001/StarWebPrnt/SendMessage. As I was developing my app, I built an alternative route within my server to record/process/display the document I received from the SDK, allowing me to have some confidence when it came time to more thorough testing on an iPad.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. You are absolutely right, it is not going to happen. I spoke to Star technicians in the UK. The WebPRNT SDK is meant to be used for web pages which would be run within the Star WebPRNT Browser. I am told currently browsers cannot communicate with Bluetooth devices. If you change your answer accordingly I will accept it.

Comment: @RichardAQuadling Does SML 200 supports label printing ? 
Can anyone help me with its xml formatting ?

Comment: @RichardAQuadling any help on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390374/how-to-connect-to-a-sk1-sanei-thermal-printer-using-star-webprnt-js-sdk-connecte